# failed to flush buffer. No buffer to flush with ob_end_flush() method

Tags: php, hhvm

My site is streaming mp3 file, intermittenly I saw Notice error in log file:

```
Notice: failed to flush buffer. No buffer to flush in
```

Below is the code:

```
$filename = 'audio.mp3';
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename);
header("X-Pad: avoid browser bug");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
ob_clean();
flush();
set_time_limit(0);
$size = filesize($filename); 
$chunksize = 1 * (1024 * 1024);
if ($size > $chunksize) {
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    $buffer = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize);
        ob_start();
        echo $buffer;
        ob_end_flush();
        flush();
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    readfile($filename);
}
```

The error always refers to **ob_end_flush();** line.

Comment: ob_get_length() if unsure if you read anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, looking at the [PHP source for `ob_flush()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/9003d8a4cfe810b9222273a36b9be89dda94a35b/main/output.c#L1335), which is where the "`failed to flush buffer. No buffer to flush`" error is being generated, it appears that error is generated if there's no active output buffer.

Based on the PHP source, `ob_end_flush()` should never result in that error - it can't, it's not in the code.  Are you sure you don't have an `ob_flush()` somewhere in your code that you're not including in what you're sharing with us in your question?

Anyway, you're not checking the return value of `ob_start()` - it can fail, and if it fails to create a new output buffer, then a subsequent `ob_flush()` or `ob_end_flush()` will fail because those commands require an active output buffer in order to function, and if there isn't one, they will emit errors.

You can see in the [PHP source for `ob_end_flush()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/81f23057dc79c320653ffa53f333facc72de4ea2/main/output.c#L1392) that the error it emits when there is no active output buffer is "`failed to delete and flush buffer. No buffer to delete or flush`".

Comment: yes I'm sure. That's the only code for the streaming. Other codes (thousands lines) are just the mp3 files. You might be right about the return value of ob_start(), but I just can't reproduce the error on myself. Probably because multiple users access, one of them will intermittenly fails. Thank you anyway.